# How can I know when an actor removed in libgdx?

Tags: libgdx

Is their a way to know when an actor had been removed from the stage? (event?)
I need to know when it removed and not meant to be removed.

Comment: In which case do you consider an actor to be "meant to be removed"? AFAIK there is no such thing. They are either removed, or not removed.

Comment: ok, how can I get a notification when an actor was remove from stage?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There's nothing like that. You will usually remove actors yourself, so you could just fire a custom event there.

It's also not possible to create a new kind of `Stage` which would fire an event like this, because `Stage` doesn't actually know the actors directly. `Stage` has a "root" `Group` which has children. Those children can also have children and when calling `Actor.remove()` the actor actually just removes itself from the parent's list of children. This would be a good place to fire an event like this, however the parent `Group` might even not be attached to a `Stage`. Furthermore, creating a new `Actor` or `Group` class which fires an event like this would not work in case you are using "native" scene2d.ui, since those already extend the native libgdx classes. Your only option here would be a change of the libgdx implementation to add this default behaviour.

It's probably easier to just call an event listener method yourself whenever you do `Actor.remove()`.

Comment: eventually this is what I tried to do.
I use notify but it doesn't work. How do I launch an event?

Comment: I didn't think of an actual `Event` like `InputEvent` for example. I thought about something like this: http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Observer_pattern.

Answer (score 2):

You can override `setStage(Stage stage)` and when `stage` is `null` thas is your time to act...

Look at this:

```
@Override
protected void setStage(Stage stage) {
    super.setStage(stage);

    if (stage != null) {
        // Actor added to stage
    } else {
        // Actor removed from stage
    }
}
```

This is probably a conceptual wrong way, because Scene2d is designed to not manage this kind of events. But sometimes it is really necessary to have such a hook. Perhaps solution described by @noone is better, but this is a cleaner way.